# How to generate a >5 MB blob for an Apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, blob

I am writing a test class for a file uploader thingamajig I wrote. The class takes a blob representing the contents of the file. So far everything is going well and I've got 93% code coverage.

However, I'm a perfectionist and I want to bring that figure up to 100%. There's a part of my code that handles an exception that gets thrown when the file is too large to be inserted in the Documents object (a file over 5mb). I want to know if there's a way I can generate a blob over 5 MB in my test class to trigger that exception handler.

How do I generate a blob over 5MB programmatically in an Apex class? I tried making a massive string the way I would in python (i.e. `String reallyBigString = "foo" * some_huge_number_here;`) but that doesn't work since Apex doesn't allow arithmetic operations on a string. Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the string `repeat` method to build a long string, and then pass that to a `Blob`.

```
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('a'.repeat(5242880));
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius. I just changed it to 5542880 since 5242880 wasn't big enough. Got that 100% coverage now. You're awesome

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: For those who find this answer in the future -- note you will get "System.LimitException: String is too long" if you try to generate a string that is much longer than this.  Anything above 6,000,000 characters throws this exception.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!